# preg_replace function removing spaces from the string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I try to build a Tagging System and it works fine there is an issue with function preg_replace(), it removes unnecessary spaces from the string.

An example of that is if my string is that

> Hey !
>
> @Yosi
>
> @Ben

Spaces will be removed and it will become to that:

> Hey!
>
> @Yosi@Ben

It seems because my condition in preg_replace included as a string.

My code:

```
$String = preg_replace ('/(\s|^)@'.$Memory['Name'][$x].'(\s|$)/', '[URL="http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/member.php?u='.$Memory['UserID'][$x].'"]@'.$Memory['Name'][$x].'[/URL]', $String);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex strips any spaces, because that's what it looks for with `(\s|^)`.

1. Either use lookaround assertions `(?<=\s|^)` and `(?=\s|$)` there.
2. Or assert non-wordy characters `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` instead.
3. Or even just reinsert them into your substitution text with `$1` and `$2`.

Also, your preg_replace looks like it is used in a loop. It's much simpler to just check all potential usernames by using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) like:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback("/(?<!\w)@(\w+)(?!\w)/",
    function($m) use ($names) {
        list($asis, $name) = $m;
        if ($isset($names[$name])) {
            return "[URL=....]";
        }
        else return $asis;
    },
    $string
);
```

Style advise: And avoid uppercase variable names. PHP isn't BASIC.

Comment: Ty, it works! i use in $1 and $2 for get back spaces. ;D